# How to return the ID autogenerated from Repository to the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room

I have a big problem that I'm not able to resolve. I'm developing a "reminder app" that allows you to insert a Memo and notify you when It's time to do it. Well, I'm using Room in Android and when I'm inserting a new task I want to use the id of the inserted task as id for manage the notification. I have both TaskViewModel and TaskRepository. This is the code I wrote:

**In the DAO I have:**

```
@Insert
long insert(Task task);
```

**In the Main activity I have:**

```
Task task = new Task(title, data_calendario, time, priority, type, note, "pending");
taskViewModel.insert(task);
```

**In the TaskViewModel I have:**

```
public void insert(Task task){
    repository.insert(task);
}
```

**In the TaskRepository I have:**

```
public void insert(Task task){
    new InsertTaskAsyncTask(taskDao).execute(task);
}

private class InsertTaskAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Task, Void, Long>{
    private TaskDao taskDao;


    private InsertTaskAsyncTask(TaskDao taskDao){
        this.taskDao = taskDao;
    }


    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Task... tasks) {

      Long test = taskDao.insert(tasks[0]);

      System.out.println("Stampa repository BUONO: "+test); //here I have the id that I need (I think..)

     return test;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long test) {
        super.onPostExecute(test);
        id = test;
    }
}
```

I read that It is possibile to retrive from the Insert method the id of the row inserted (I have an auto-generated int Id on my task_table as primary key) that should be what I need.
Now my question is, how can i return the id of my inserted Task from my **TaskRepository** to my **MainActivity** for the creation of the notification?
Thank you in advance for the help

**A Little Step**

In the Repository I set a `private long id;` variable.

Inside onPostExecute I set `id=test;` as you can see in the code above, and I create a method like this:

```
public long getId(){
    return id;
}
```

that it is called from the MainActivity, after the insert method.
The problem is that the first time i run the app and create a Task the value in this variable is always 0. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Based on the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert) (below the code snippet)

A method annotated with the `@Insert` annotation can return:

- `long` for single insert operation
- `long[]` or `Long[]` or `List<Long>` for multiple insert operations
- `void` if you don't care about the inserted id(s)

Comment: Yes, I read that but I can't figure out how to pass the ID trough the Repository, the ViewModel and save the value in the MainActivity. Someone can show me a sample of the code? What did I do wrong?